# How to connect node.js to kerberos kafka cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, apache-kafka, kerberos

I want to connect a Kerberos Kafka cluster using node.js. I researched some NPM packages those offer Kafka connectivity, but did not find anything specific to connect to the Kerberos Kafka cluster. if anyone has done this before, please provide some direction.

Comment: If anybody have any pointers on this, please share

Comment: I am still looking for the answer..

Answer (score 2):

[node-rdkafka](https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka) wraps librdkafka which supports SASL.

This link shows how to configure librdkafka for Kerberos authentication:
https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/Using-SASL-with-librdkafka

Comment: Thanks I will try this out